# Loaded nib but the view outlet was not set - UITableViewController

Tags: ios, interface-builder, ios7, xcode5

I know this question has been asked dozens of times. I've real all answers on SO but still cannot find the issue :((((

I get `Loaded nib but the view outlet was not set` when I'm trying to activate view with  `UITableViewController`.

Could you please help me ? Below is my xib. I added connections out of desperation but it doesn't help.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<document type="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder3.CocoaTouch.XIB" version="3.0" toolsVersion="4504" systemVersion="12E55" targetRuntime="iOS.CocoaTouch" propertyAccessControl="none" useAutolayout="YES">
    <dependencies>
        <deployment defaultVersion="1536" identifier="iOS"/>
        <plugIn identifier="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder.IBCocoaTouchPlugin" version="3734.1"/>
    </dependencies>
    <objects>
        <placeholder placeholderIdentifier="IBFirstResponder" id="-2" customClass="UIResponder"/>
        <tableViewController id="Ure-ya-PJB" customClass="BRSMyListRootViewController">
            <tableView key="view" opaque="NO" clipsSubviews="YES" clearsContextBeforeDrawing="NO" contentMode="scaleToFill" alwaysBounceVertical="YES" style="plain" separatorStyle="default" rowHeight="44" sectionHeaderHeight="22" sectionFooterHeight="22" id="NFR-CB-kzq">
                <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="320" height="568"/>
                <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask" widthSizable="YES" heightSizable="YES"/>
                <color key="backgroundColor" white="1" alpha="1" colorSpace="calibratedWhite"/>
            </tableView>
            <simulatedStatusBarMetrics key="simulatedStatusBarMetrics"/>
            <nil key="simulatedTopBarMetrics"/>
            <nil key="simulatedBottomBarMetrics"/>
            <simulatedOrientationMetrics key="simulatedOrientationMetrics"/>
            <simulatedScreenMetrics key="simulatedDestinationMetrics" type="retina4"/>
            <refreshControl key="refreshControl" opaque="NO" multipleTouchEnabled="YES" contentMode="center" enabled="NO" contentHorizontalAlignment="center" contentVerticalAlignment="center" id="jJO-vh-VBh">
                <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask"/>
            </refreshControl>
            <connections>
                <outlet property="view" destination="NFR-CB-kzq" id="RYK-D4-fda"/>
                <outlet property="tableView" destination="NFR-CB-kzq" id="RYK-D4-fdb"/>
            </connections>
        </tableViewController>
    </objects>
</document>
```

My interface looks like this

```
@interface BRSMyListRootViewController : UITableViewController
@end
```

and the implementation is quite big. I posted it on Gist here: https://gist.github.com/cppexpert/6364570

The way I initialize this controller is this:

```
UINavigationController *vc0 = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:
                               [[BRSMyListRootViewController alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain]];
UINavigationController *vc1 = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:
                               [[BRSCheckInViewController alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStyleGrouped]];

self.tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
[self.tabBarController setViewControllers:@[vc0, vc1]];

[self.window setRootViewController:self.tabBarController];
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible]; // It crashes here.
```

I checked in the debugger and see that `view` and `tableView` properties are set. So I cannot understand what exactly is wrong :(

Comment: "I checked in the debugger and see that `view` and `tableView` properties are set." What's *not* set then?..

Comment: @dasblinkenlight I don't know. That's why I don't understand why it still crashes.

Comment: If properties weren't set, they would be `nil`, so the thing wouldn't crash. Does it contain random stuff?

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Are you referring to `view` and `tableView` ? Yes, they have values. I'm not sure if values have random stuff. It looks legit to me. How can I pin-point what property is not set ? Maybe I can put breakpoint somewhere ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like it was Xcode 5's bug.

I did clean checkout from github and compared folder.

There were no code changes. Only different files were:

- MyProject.xcccheckout
- UserInterfaceState.xcuserstate

Recovering `UserInterfaceState.xcuserstate` made exception disappear.

So keep this in mind, guys. Problem may not even be in your code.